# Datepicker jquery mobile change color of day

Tags: jquery-mobile, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

It is possible through the datepicker of jquery mobile change the colors of the day?

I have three dates like this:

1. **2012/06/01**
2. **2012/06/05**
3. **2012/06/18**

And I want these dates are visible in datepicker (red for example) and when clicked on one of these dates were executed an action!

Is it possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what Date Picker you're using but DateBox:

- http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/

Offers Themes:

- http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/theme/

You could make two themes and toggle between the two to get the effect you wanted

Comment: I'm using these: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/experiments/ui-datepicker/ and I want only the color red in those days

Comment: That's an alpha version from a while back, jQM is coming up on version 1.2 soon. I would suggestion upgrading if possible

Comment: It's better to use datebox than datepicker?

Comment: yes datepicker is not release nor supported, nor is the alpha version of jQM you are using. Much has been improved in performance and device support with the latest build